# Recent Documents Click Launches Nautilus Rather Than File

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, zeitgeist

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and recently, I've noticed that whenever I click on a 'recent document' from either the "Recent Documents" list in my Cairo Dock or from my journalling extension in GNOME Shell, the directory the file is in, is opened in Nautilus rather than the actual file.

I have not been able to find a solution online.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The Recent Documents listing will always be listed in Nautilus. It will take you to a folder in Nautilus listing the most lately edited files. Having 'one' file open even if its the only one you have edited will still bring it up.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer at https://answers.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+question/193455.  Deleting the mimeapps.list file at ~/.local/share/applications fixed my problem.  I don't know how it had gotten corrupted, but at least it's working fine now.